# Mosaic-Decisions: Flow import/export by API

Tags: mosaic-decisions

We have 21 mosaic instances, It is very difficult to migrate flows on 21 environment. We have to make this process automatically by CICD pipeline.

How can we import/export mosaic flow by API? If it is available please mention steps.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: by API I am assuming you are asking for a feature wherein a flow can be migrated via hitting a generated API? or are you asking the migration strategy in general?

Comment: @codeogeek Thanks for the instant reply. For instance, keep API aside. Is there any mechanism where we can import/export flows by the terminal as like MOSAIC UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Mosaic Decisions has the provision of Flow migration. Following migrations are available in Mosaic Decisions -

1. Single flow export-import
2. Bulk flow export-import
3. Whole Project export-import

As you mentioned about triggering it through terminal, It can be done in 2 steps,

1. Hitting curl command on the API meant to export the flow/s
2. Hitting curl command on the API meant to import the flow/s

Please note, you need to have access to the cluster and the project where the flow/s are getting imported.

In the coming versions, Mosaic Decisions will also come with export-import happening through a single hit through UI or hitting a single API.

Hope this resolves your query.
For API related queries, you can connect with the product support of Mosaic.

Comment: Do we have an option to migrate mosaic schedules too? (where we have multiple Flows chained with inter-dependencies)